# Backward data-flow: post-order or RPO on reverse CFG?

Tags: compilers, graph-traversal, data-flow-analysis

When solving backward data-flow problems, many resources (Wikipedia and many presentations found online) recommend traversing the control-flow graph (CFG) in post-order for fastest convergence, which makes sense.

Other resources (such as the "Engineering a Compiler" book) suggest to use reverse post-order (RPO) on the reversed CFG instead.

... and PO(graph) != RPO(rev(graph)) in some cases involving cycles.

My question is: which resource is right? Post-order makes sense, so why not just use that and save the CFG inversion? Why would I use RPO on reversed CFG instead?

Comment: I had exactly the same question. Please let me know if you had the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Seems OP has some good guess on this question, https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/directed-graph-traversal-orderings-and-applications-to-data-flow-analysis/

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly due to the speed of convergence. To clarify, RPO visits as many predecessors possible before visiting a node so in case of forward data flow problems (like Dominator computation) this would help to converge faster. You can find more details in Engineering a compiler book (which you already know!)